# How to multiple forward for one request in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have some config:

```
 server {
        listen 192.168.1.3:81;
      location /dlr {
                rewrite .* /rf/sms/status/ break;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1/;
                proxy_set_header HOST www.example.com;
                proxy_set_header      Authorization "Basic";
                access_log /var/log/nginx/1.access.log cntl_log;
        }
     location /mt {
                rewrite .* /rf/sms/receive/ break;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1/;
                proxy_set_header HOST www.example.com;
                proxy_set_header      Authorization "Basic";
                access_log /var/log/nginx/2.access.log cntl_log;
        }
}
```

I need to forward the same query to one more another address, with a slightly different configuration, but location the same. How can I do this?

Comment: `upstream` does not fit me, because i needed set `proxy_set_header HOST www.example1.com` for another server

Comment: This question arise every month or so and still answer is: not possible. you need different tool. Probably haproxy could do this.